# How to allow an npm script to run all tasks before terminating even if one task fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an NPM script that runs multiple tasks like this:

```
"multiple": "task1 && task2 && task3"
```

However if `tasks2` fails, the script will terminate and `task3` will not be run.

Is there a way to "Catch" / "Ignore" the error if it does occur, so that `task3` runs either way?

Something like:

"multiple": "task1 && task2 > ignore && task3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `;` instead of `&&`:

```
"multiple": "task1 && task2 ; task3"
```

`&&` is logical "and" with short-circuit. It stops the chain immediatly when the result is clear (`false`) and doesn't evaluate the remaining operations.

Comment: So if I understand correctly we should put the `;` after any task that we want to allow to fail, yet keep the following task running right?

Comment: @Ole That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

to continue running all tasks even if one of them fails by adding the `--ignore-scripts` flag.

Here's how I would modify the package.json file:

```json
"scripts": {
  "my-script": "task1 && task2 && task3 || true"
}
```

In the example above, the `&&` operator is used to run each task sequentially. The `|| true` statement is added at the end to ensure that the script continues to run even if one of the tasks fails.

OR you could try the `--force` flag, which will force npm to continue running the script even if errors are thrown.

```json
"scripts": {
  "my-script": "npm run task1 && npm run task2 && npm run task3 --force"
}
```

Comment: The `|| true' did not work for me.  I think if we put it after the task that may fail it might ...